# Can't open ofstream locally

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

i am a Computer Science student. i was given an assignment that needs to use the following code:
(those are the first lines of my main() code)

```
ofstream OutFile1("output1.txt");
if( !OutFile1.is_open() )
{
    
    cout << "Error opening output1.txt!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

for some reason i have an error opening the ofstream on my computer.
i sent the full code to my guide and he says it works on his computer.
i tried reinstalling my VS in different ways and it doesnt seem to help..

anyone has an idea how to check the reason for the error or how to solve it?

Comment: The open will fail unless a file `output1.txt` exists in correct place (the working directory) and your account have a permission to read the file.

Comment: *i sent the full code to my guide and he says it works on his computer* -- That's all the guide said?  Not "the file probably doesn't exist in the correct place"?  Get a new guide.  --- *i tried reinstalling my VS in different ways and it doesnt seem to help..* -- So you uninstalled the compiler for such a simple issue as the file not being able to be opened?  If you put in the full path of the file instead of just the file name, see if the file opens.

Comment: In Visual Studio Community, Pro or Enterprise the default working directory when executing your application from the IDE is the project directory. This is set in the Debugger settings of the project as $(ProjectDir) which is a VS IDE variable that contains the path of the project. In other IDEs and if you execute from the file explorer the working directory will likely be the location of the executable.

Comment: @MikeCAT the file doesn't have to exist. it will be created. He is using ofstream, not ifstream.

Comment: Check the value of `errno` after `is_open` returns false.  It should give you a clue as to why you are not able to create the file.

Comment: You may want to write some simple text to the file, like "I eat cannibals\n".  Then search your folders to find the file.

Comment: I have tested the code you provided, it also works on my computer. I suggest you to check whether the .txt was created successfully? If so, whether this .txt have permission to open and write? I suggest you could try to run vs with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do not have write permissions to an existing "output1.txt" file or you do not have write permissions to the working directory.

Comment: Makes a decent comment, but it's not much of an answer. A good answer will provide a solution.